# Why is “learning hard” wrong yet “studying hard” is right?

Tags: grammaticality, collocation, modifiers, predicate-frames

Why does saying *learning hard* sound so terribly wrong and unnatural, given that *working hard, exercising hard,
listening hard, thinking hard,* and even *it rains hard* sound perfectly natural and get said all the time?

I know that we can add *hard* to something when we’re talking about doing
something hard to accomplish or doing something with a lot of effort.

Then why can’t I just *learn hard*?

Sometimes learning something can be very challenging, or I can try to do
the act of learning so hard like *studying hard* and *working hard* with a lot of
effort and energy.

Why shouldn’t “learning hard” be the act of “doing hard”?

Comment: Because _learning_ is not something you are in control of, whereas _studying_ is.

Comment: learning is not something we are in control of?? but, don’t we do the act of learning deliberately?
We learn a language, a musical instrument, and skills such as dancing, skiing, and, going even further, we learn science, history, math, etc. some of them definitely require us to at least make an effort so eventually, somehow, it could lead us to the point where we have to learn those things “hard”.

Comment: To learn is to acquire knowledge or a skill; we do that by studying a subject or practising an activity. It's true that we say things like "I'm learning French", but what this really means is "I'm studying it". We can say "I'm working hard at learning French", but we can't actually control the amount of knowledge we acquire. Some people pick up knowledge or skills more easily than others.

Comment: Something can be hard to learn but you can't [say] "learn hard". You can study hard to learn; or you can practise hard to learn; or you can try hard to learn. Learning is not an action like working, studying, practising, trying, listening etc.; it is more like the result of the action.

Comment: As @ermanen and John Lawler said. Learning is not an action but the intended result. Just as you can look hard but not see hard; listen hard but not hear hard; search hard but not find hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/learn) shows the different subsenses of **learn** relevant here nicely:

> *learn* [transitive verb]: 1a(1): to gain knowledge or understanding
> of or skill in by
>
> - (i) study,
> - (ii) instruction, or
> - (iii) experience
>
> [last classification labelling, i/ii/iii, mine].

In spite of M-W's ordering here, I'd say that the default subsense is the 'assimilate knowledge, understanding, wisdom ... often not by design' subsense (ie iii) rather than the 'set oneself to learn by study and practice' (i) subsense. So, with this subsense not highlighting application, design, the intensifier 'hard' makes no sense.

- Work / try / practise / play / study / think ... hard.

But *not* the non-applicational

- *Understand / dream / appreciate / pick up / realise / discover / **learn** [default sense] ... hard.

So I'd say you're on the right track ... the complication is that 'learn' is very polysemous.

Comment: Maybe  *hard* has its own constraints. You can ✅hit hard but not ❌catch hard. You can ✅wish hard but not ❌want hard. You can ✅close a door hard but you can’t ❌open it hard. You can ✅try hard but you can hardly ❌win hard nor ❌succeed hard. You can ✅think hard but you can’t ❌remember hard, ❌realize hard, or ❌know hard. Can you ❓teach hard? You can ✅live hard and maybe ❓die hard, but the first didn’t ❌cause hard the second. You can ✅fly hard and ✅grip hard but ❗falling hard and ❗landing hard are different, just as a hose ✅spraying hard is hardly like mud ❗drying hard. Can the sun ❓shine hard?

Comment: @tchrist - I'm bedazzled.  How did you do that?

Comment: @aparente001 I found somewhere that had them and then used copy-paste with my mouse.

Comment: @tchrist - So, would you give inquiring minds the `code`?

Comment: @aparente001 Typing `perl -CS -le 'print "\x{2705} \x{274C} \x{2753} \x{2757}"'` into a system console where `perl` is installed produces a line containing `✅ ❌ ❓ ❗`. So does `perl -CS -le 'print "\N{WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK} \N{CROSS MARK} \N{BLACK QUESTION MARK ORNAMENT} \N{HEAVY EXCLAMATION MARK SYMBOL}"'` for that matter, or simply `perl -Mutf8 -CSA -E 'say "✅ ❌ ❓ ❗"'`  itself. I just used my mouse to copy each one at a time into the comment.

Comment: @tchrist - Sorry, does that mean I would have to have perl installed on my computer for this to work?  I mean, I guess I could do that, but I want to make sure I understood.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the list of words that can take "hard" as some sort of figurative adverb has been in expansion through my lifetime, and I suspect that Madison Avenue (that is, the advertising industry) must have played a big role in that.

I will propose a simple way for you to decide whether *hard* will fit or not.  Think *cause and effect*.  "Studying" is the cause, and "learning" is (hopefully) the effect.

Here's a non-figurative use of *hard* (as an adverb):

> I hit my head hard.

Comment: But 'I spent many long hours learning the multiplication tables' (volition, application) whereas *'Yes, I really learned hard'. I think the interplay of the senses of 'learn' is significant.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Interesting point.  Although I won't be around to see it, I suspect that in several generations, "learning hard" may be common parlance.